# What is the STM32 "timestamp" feature designed for?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, rtc

While browsing the [stm32f051xx datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f051r8.pdf) I came across this section (p23, section 3.15, Real-time clock (RTC) and backup registers)

> timestamp feature which can be used to save the calendar content. This function can
>   be triggered by an event on the timestamp pin, or by a tamper event. The MCU can be
>   woken up from Stop and Standby modes on timestamp event detection

As I understand it, this allows you to take a snapshot of the date and time that a pin change occurs either with or without waking up. However, there is no further explanation of this feature, even in the RTC application notes.

I could see obvious uses for this feature if you could save multiple timestamps, or it had sub-second accuracy. However, none of that is available. I assume this feature must be commonly useful to be included, so I'm curious what kind of use-cases this feature was designed in mind with.

Comment: Data logging...

Comment: @DKNguyen but you can store only a single timestamp. And on many models, not even sub-second accuracy.

Comment: That's why you then move it to more long term storage afterwards. There's not really much point in trying to understand why a feature exists when you don't need it.

Comment: @DKNguyen but if you need to wake up to store it, then what's the point? You can just use a normal pin-change interrupt. I can't decide if I want a feature if I don't know what it's for.

Comment: it takes time to wake up ... sub-second data is mentioned as being available

Comment: @Azsgy You speak as if you pay extra for the features that come with a microcontroller, and as if you must use all the features that come with a microcontroller, and as if get to choose the exact feature set you want with a microcontroller. This is not like a car where you pick and pay for each little thing you want it to come with. If you don't want to use a feature, just don't use it.

Comment: It is a toolbox full of tools, hammer, saw, screwdrivers, etc.YOU choose what to do with them even so far as to hammer the back end of a screwdriver to punch a hole in something which is not what the tool was designed for but if it works,then hey...They are describing the toolbox,as pointed out you dont have to use all the tools,pretty much never will you use all the tools in a project,and it is up to you to determine how and why to use the tools not the tool designer or some god of design that says this thing was only made to be used for one thing and you are forbidden to use it any other way

Comment: @old_timer if a kid picks up a screwdriver and asks "what was this made for", there is an obvious answer: fastening screws. Saying "you can do whatever you want" or "you don't need it" isn't a helpful answer to that question. Tools are, by definition, designed for a purpose, and I'm asking what that purpose is.

Comment: The tool is designed for a specific purpose: to accurately save a single timestamp while asleep. It's not useful to you much like the screwdriver is not useful to someone who is surrounded by socket bolts and cannot reasonably use a screwdriver to interact with them.

Comment: @Azsgy if a kid picks up a screwdriver and doesnt know what it is they are not ready to use it...

Comment: its an RTC, it has some generic time related functions including being able to take a snapshot of the time, for whatever reason you might want to snapshot a time and can connect your event through that trigger.  Period, done.

Comment: If you are looking for a 32 bit ADC that can sample 20Mhz, this is not the part for you.  If you want to capture the time of events at 10Mhz this is probably not the tool for you.  You want to have a clock that is accurate enough to your clock source and can sample time with some accuracy but not a high sample rate, then maybe this is the part for you.

Comment: It is a valid question, what could this be used for, it wasnt DESIGNED for some special everyone knows but you purpose, its just a tool.  Its just not a stackoverflow question, too broad, primarily opinion based, isnt a single answer.  Now maybe you can try it at programmers stackexchange you see questions like this there...But you need to work on the question before you ask it and change how you ask it even for that site, you went beyond the timestamp into generic programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think the explanation in the reference manual gives one good use case for the feature: *Tamper event*. This may be the main reason of existence of this feature. For example, by using it you can say "Analyzing the device logs, we determined that you have opened the case of the product on [some date & time]. So, the product warranty is void."